# BagOfFeatures for Image Category Classification in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

Doing this example in Matlab [Image Category Classification](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html#zmw57dd0e1092)
I have found an error trying to get the vocabulary of SURF features with this command

```
bag = bagOfFeatures(trainingSet);
```

The error is the following

```
Error using bagOfFeatures/parseInputs (line 1023)
The value of 'imgSets' is invalid. Expected imgSets to be one of these types:

imageSet

Instead its type was matlab.io.datastore.ImageDatastore.
```

I am using a ImageDatastore input instead of imgSets, but I am following a Mathworks example. Anyone can explain me why is this happening and how can I convert trainingSet into a imgSets type?

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same problem. Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the ImageDatastore object to an imageSet object. This can simply be done by using the following line instead:

```
bagOfFeatures(imageSet(trainingSet.Files));
```

Comment: It's a matter of new data structure deployed by the Toolbox developer. It doesn't change anything with the BoF concept.